Solar off-grid configuration to run heavy electrical appliance
I have around 15 solar panels rated 330 W which goes unused most of the time. I use them for 6 hours in a week tops for irrigation purpose. So I am looking out to put the panels to use while idle.
I am looking forward to run the equipment 24x7, but I am not able to get the calculation right to come to the required batteries and inverter.

Total wattage of all electrical equipment put together: 3500 Wh. Not considering the power consumption of inverter itself.
Solar Panels already procured: 15 panels with 330 W rating - Total energy rating 4950 W
The devices must run 24x7
Sunlight expectation - 6 hours of strong sunlight and remaining 5 hours medium to low
Complete off-grid setup with no backup from grid.

I have read that power losses has to be factored etc. but I am completely lost on how to design the configuration. I have reached out to couple of solar consultants for details but all I am receiving is conflicting information.
I would like some right pointers and literature which helps me design and validate my understanding.
Thanks.

Get numbers for Solarity , rain, dust , elevation and azimuth loss, unless servo aims PVs  at the sun and kept clean continuously. Then define cost/consequences of insufficient power for a day or more.

your load is 3500 Wh. + 10% loss, then consider at least 1 day storage capacity of 4000 Wh and use grid for backup charger. This way you won't ruin your deep-cell batteries by cycling too deep.

You have power and energy mixed up. 4950 W is a power. 3500 Wh is energy.

Read about power and energy, you really need to get your terms straight before discussing stuff like this. It's like mixing up speed and distance and asking how much fuel do I need in my tank to do 60 mph, can I get to my destination at 40 mph?

As the question has an error about power vs energy, I've added some "Solar Basics" at the end.
Start with looking at a well-known source for typical data in your area, such as the World Bank's https://globalsolaratlas.info which will give the basic outputs typical of a particular place, using Tokyo just as an example.

Screengrab from https://globalsolaratlas.info
For example, it says Tokyo will get 3.7 kWh per day per 1000 watts of panel: thus with 4950 Watts of panel you'd get on average a raw 18.3 kWh each day.  Out of which comes conversion, storage, and ageing losses.  In a perfect system with no losses, 18.3 kWh would run 760 W continuously (18,300 Wh / 24 h = 760 W), or your 3,500 W load for 5.2 hours (18,300 Wh / 3,500 W = 5.2 h)
So, even under perfect conditions, you're a long way short of running 3.5 kW continuously: you're going to need more panels or a smaller load or less hours per day.
But also of course a) the system isn't perfect, b) some days are not so sunny, c) you must decide how "improbable" do you want your downtime to be, and of course, d) what happens during maintenance?
How much headroom you put in depends on the answers to these questions.  For sense checking, I'd start with 50% of output, perhaps 24-48 hours of storage.  (It depends a lot on whether the thing is powering dialysis or salt mills, and how many cycles you want your batteries to last.)  If you're designing to 10% margins, that's way too close for first estimates.
Think about how many day's worth of battery you are comfortable with.  Batteries often are more problematic than you'd imagine.  Don't forget that panels age; don't forget cleaning the panels (leaves, dust, bird fouling). If you've got a lot of space, consider non-battery storage (pump water up a hill, drive a water generator).  If you're completely off-grid, make sure your control and monitoring systems have something more reliable than the main system.
The most common professional modelling software is PVSyst which covers a lot more detail and is typically used to model an individual site with specific panels and invertors and so on  It's expensive but there are trials and educational rates.  If you've got local solar engineers you could ask them to run some numbers for you and give you the report it makes.  I am sure there are good open source modelling programs but I'm not familiar with them.
If you've got a simple system I'm assuming it's fixed at some angle.  If it can track, it's a lot more complex; also if you're in open country I'm assuming no significant shading, which is even more complex.  But if (as it seems) you've already got the panels installed, consider dummy loads and measuring.
Solar Basics

Panels are rated in "peak" or "nominal" power, which is how much power they give when under certain test conditions which are approximately "facing the sun on a standard sunny day".
Yours give 330 W under those conditions.  Less if it's hazy, more if it's extra sunny, nothing at night.
Vitally: less if it comes in at an angle, such as the world turning.
If you leave your 330 W panel in Straight-On Standard Sunny for an hour, you'd get 330 watt-hours of energy, for two hours you'd get 660 Wh.
How much you actually get for a given place on earth, for typical weather, is known for most of the world, and you look it up as shown above.
In some imaginary perfect system, by conservation of energy, 660 Wh would power a 1 W lamp for 660 hours, or a 660 of those lamps for 1 hour or any other power-time product equal to 660 Wh
Most solar engineering is about where the losses and other imperfections are, such as conversion losses.
But much trickier issues are non-linearities in battery charging and ways in which impaired panels affect the whole system.
Of course you'll see the SI unit for energy is the joule, which is a watt-second, but solar engineering almost always uses the watt-hour because it's more convenient.  1 watt-hour = 3600 watt-seconds, aka joules.


Thanks for the detailed answer, I am open to add more panels provided the costing works out. I would want to factor in how many batteries I have to purchase, the inverter cost and additional panels cost in total to do project costing and take it forward. In local I do not see any good advice coming up, that's where I turned up to SO but unfortunately my question is being closed for being off topic :(

You might rewrite your question to be more clearly about the design of a solar system for driving a particular load, and get the question reopened.
